# How to format ZonedDateTime with spring data audit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i want to use Spring Data Audit for my Entities and i'm not sure about the format that will be produced in DB. Here is my abstract class for auditing:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractFullAuditEntity {

    @CreatedDate
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    public ZonedDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    public ZonedDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    private @CreatedBy String createdBy;

    private @LastModifiedBy String lastModifiedBy;

}
```

If i save some entity, my db entries contain something like this:

Created_date: aced00057372000d6a6176612e74696d652e536572955d84ba1b2248b20c00007870771f06000007e0020b0a332f23c346000407000d4575726f70652f4265726c696e78

Is it correct format and why does it not look like '2016-01-01 14:54 ...'? Does it mean that i can not search for created_date with SQL?

Comment: Are you going to share what is the DB table structure? column types? and the INSERT statement that put the data there? Doesn't look like a DATE/TIMESTAMP column to me

Comment: The column type is VARBINARY. I'm using H2 DB now for my test. It was auto generated by hibernate.

Comment: so there is your problem. Is ZonedDateTime (i.e JDK8 java.time types) a supported type in Hibernate? In JPA as a minimum you ought to have @Temporal on it.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated hibernate to version 5.1 and use hibernate-java8 lib. It works for me now.